# How do I get node.js & Mocha to run (test) in browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

In Win10.64 I'm running the test on the command line with expected results:

```
>mocha test
   Array
     #indexOf()
       √ should return -1 when the value is not present
   1 passing (16ms)
```

But in Chrome, console error is: **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(anonymous function) @ test.lead-helper.js:1**

test.lead-helper.js:

```
var assert = require("assert");

describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function () {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function () {
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(5));
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(0));
    });
  });
});
```

and the HTML test runner:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mocha Tests</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <div id="fixtures"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/jquery/2.1.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Automattic/expect.js/0.3.1/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.3.0/chai.js"></script>
    <script src="lead-helper.js"></script>
    <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
    <script src="test/test.lead-helper.js"></script>
    <script>
      mocha.checkLeaks();
      mocha.globals(['jQuery']);
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be working at cross-purpose. You load Chai:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.3.0/chai.js"></script>
```

which is a full-featured assertion library but then you use `require("assert")` which seems to be an attempt at loading Node's `assert` library into your browser. There may be a way to get this to load by using Browserify but I don't see why you'd do that, seeing as you already load Chai, and there is no indication that the rest of your code needs Browserify.

I would just remove the `require` call and instead have:

```
var assert = chai.assert;
```

Comment: I also added to the top of the test file:

    `var chai = chai || require('chai');
    var assert = chai.assert;`
so now the test runs both in the browser _and_ on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because there is no `require()` method in browser environment by default, so you have to make some changes in your script moduling. There are some ways you can go:

- Use other method to load scripts, for example with the help
  `<script>` tag.
- Use CommonJS implementation, like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), or [Component](https://github.com/component/component).
- Use AMD implementation like [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Thanks! Please help me understand the first option: `<script>` tag (seems simplest); should I be adding one or more node.js files that way?

Comment: Well, I guess that you are using `require()` method to load a module that is excluded into a separate file. Instead of doing it, try to load every required file in that way, by using: `<script src="../path/to/script">`.

Comment: I get what you're saying now. Thank you for explaining it. Removing the unnecessary `require()` method as suggested below is what ended up making it work for me.